# Linear Algebra Simplification

Tags: linear-algebra

I am attempting to simplify the following expression:

${u_1{}}^{T}M^{-1}x-{u_2{}}^{T}M^{-1}x-\frac{1}{2}{u_1{}}^{T}M^{-1}{u_{1}}+\frac{1}{2}{u_{2}}^{T}M^{-1}{u_{2}}$

where $u$ and $x$ are vectors and $M$ is a matrix.

I've started by factoring the first two terms as so:

$({u_1{}}-{u_2{}})^{T}M^{-1}x-\frac{1}{2}{u_1{}}^{T}M^{-1}{u_{1}}+\frac{1}{2}{u_{2}}^{T}M^{-1}{u_{2}}$

However, now I am stuck on how to further reduce the third and fourth terms.  I believe there may be some property since both vectors multiplying each side of the matrix are the same, only differing in that one is a transpose.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as 
\begin{equation}
 u_1^TM^{-1}(x - \frac{1}{2}u_1)
 -
u_2^TM^{-1}(x - \frac{1}{2}u_2)
\end{equation}